# Getting the name of many properties inside a json file with reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a functional component that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Styles from './searchbar.scss'

const AutoFill = (props) => {
  const results = props.results || {}

  return (
    <ul className={Styles.searchUl}>
      {Object.entries(results).map(([key, value]) => {
        console.log('VALUE', value)
        console.log('VALUENAME', value.apple.name)
        return (
          <li className={Styles.searchLi}>
            <a className={Styles.searchA} href={value.apple.href} target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer' key={value.href}>
              {value.apple.name}
            </a>
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}

AutoFill.propTypes = {
  results: PropTypes.array
}

export default AutoFill
```

---

I also have a Json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "results": {
    "apple": {
      "name": "apple",
      "href": "https://www.apple.com/"
    },
    "armadillo": {
      "name": "armadillo",
      "href": "https://www.armadillo.com/"
    },
    "box": {
      "name": "box",
      "href": "https://www.box.com/"
    },
    "berserk": {
      "name": "berserk",
      "href": "https://www.berserk.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

---

With `console.log('Resultsssssss', (results[key].apple.name))` i get the specified name of apple only which returns obv `apple`.
So i want to know how i can return the name of all the objects at once, To show them in a UL under a searchbar for a autoFill when typed a everything of a should appear as suggestions: https://gyazo.com/006e856190e8e063934a07eb0725926e

Any answer will be highly appreciated and looked into.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return all properties within from within the map function without the for loop which you have in your code

```js
const data = {
  "results": {
    "apple": {
      "name": "apple",
      "href": "https://www.apple.com/"
    },
    "armadillo": {
      "name": "armadillo",
      "href": "https://www.armadillo.com/"
    },
    "box": {
      "name": "box",
      "href": "https://www.box.com/"
    },
    "berserk": {
      "name": "berserk",
      "href": "https://www.berserk.com/"
    }
  }
}

const res = Object.entries(data.results).map(([key, value]) => {
  return value.name;
});
console.log(res);
```

What you need for render is to restructure your HTML a little bit

```js
const data = {
  "results": {
    "apple": {
      "name": "apple",
      "href": "https://www.apple.com/"
    },
    "armadillo": {
      "name": "armadillo",
      "href": "https://www.armadillo.com/"
    },
    "box": {
      "name": "box",
      "href": "https://www.box.com/"
    },
    "berserk": {
      "name": "berserk",
      "href": "https://www.berserk.com/"
    }
  }
}

const Styles = {}
const AutoFill = (props) => {
  const results = props.results || {}

  return (
    <ul className={Styles.searchUl}>
      {Object.entries(results).map(([key, value]) => {
        return (
            <li className={Styles.searchLi}>
              <a className={Styles.searchA} href={value.href} target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer' key={value.href}>
                {value.name}
              </a>
            </li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<AutoFill results={data.results} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Comment: when i do this it says that there is a parsing error because you aren't allowed to create consts directly under a return since i want to use the data to be displayed in a html return i'll add the full file instead of the fuctions.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: It's not showing the ```{value.name}``` of the values under the searchbar for some reason

Comment: can you console.log(value) inside the map method and see if you are getting the correct values. Also `const results = props.results || []` should be `const results = props.results || {}`

Comment: I believe that i do get the correct data, https://gyazo.com/2b90c7020f26c764b04855d402804751 and i have changed what you said with the const result

Comment: Updated answer with the demo

Comment: I think that this isn't allowed in reactjs since you are using gelelementbyid?

Comment: and a question do i need to have ```ReactDOM.render(<AutoFill results={data.results} />, document.getElementById('app'))``` aswell?
I have removed i did ```console.log('VALUENAME', value.name)``` but it says ```VALUENAME undefined```

Comment: i have tried ```{value.apple.name}``` and this does get the specific name but when i do ```value.name``` that doesnt get the name of them all

Comment: It will not give your the name of them all together but since you are iterating over the data, it will work. And ReactDOM.render is used to for the DEMO since you need to render the top level element in the DOM. I think you must read the react docs to have a better understanding

Comment: Yeah, I had already read the docs for the ReactDOM i already thought that it was used for the demo, And also when i try the code you have in your demo it doesn't receive json data because when i console.logged it it said undefined

Answer (score 0):

When you passed 2 arguments in your map function, first one is general key of your json file, **results** in your case and second argument is content under this key.

Try this:

```
const AutoFill = (props) => {
  const results = props.results || []

  return (
    Object.entries(results).map(([name, content]) => {
      for (const key in content) {
        if (content.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log('Resultsssssss', (content[key].name))
        }
      }
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: I've tried your method but it shows me this error: ``` error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","````
I've edited my post, added the full file i had with the html etc can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to get all the values of the object. `Object.values(results)` will return an array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "href": "https://www.apple.com/"
  },
  {
    "name": "armadillo",
    "href": "https://www.armadillo.com/"
  },
  {
    "name": "box",
    "href": "https://www.box.com/"
  },
  {
    "name": "berserk",
    "href": "https://www.berserk.com/"
  }
]
```

Now you can use `map` to get the names: `Object.values(results).map(x => x.name)`. This will return an array of names: `['apple', 'armadillo', ...]`.

Comment: because i also have html that needs the data that is gonna be displayed inside of the function so it can refer to it but with your function it keeps saying missing ',' even when i tried everything i have included the full file.